# Set product position in category

Tags: magento, resources, url-rewriting, product

I rewrote Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product and added method _saveCategories to my class
MyCompany_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product.

This is my code:

```
$p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(32);
$p->setCategoryIds(array('0'=>14));
$p->save();
```

After product save, I expect Magento to call _saveCategories method from MyCompany_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product but it doesn't, it calls _saveCategories method from Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product.

Can somebody give me idea why is this happening?

I think class was rewriten properly, `echo get_class(Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_product'));` displays `MyCompany_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product`

Answer (score 0):

I made mistake in config.xml, I overlooked the fact that overwriting resources is not the same as overwriting modules:

I had this code in config.xml

```
    <catalog>
      <rewrite>resource_product>MyCompany_Catalog_Model_Catalog_Resource_Product</resource_product></rewrite>
   </catalog>
```

Changed it to:

```
        <catalog_resource>
                <rewrite>
                   <product>MyCompany_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product</product>
                </rewrite>
         </catalog_resource>
```

And it works.